# MSI Engine fails to start

Tags: windows-installer, installaware

We have an MSI installer created using **InstallAware**. For some mystical reason, some of the MSI files generated using the same build process fail on one particular machine. The MSI Engine fails to start and I do not even see logs created. As I result I cannot do anything with the problem. I tried disabling the **antivirus** and **firewall** if anything like that was blocking a process. This happens randomly with certain builds only. Those builds work on other machines smoothly.

Does anyone have an clue about how to approach the problem?

Comment: Do other MSIs start on this machine?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try to verify that the **Windows Installer Engine** is up to date on the machine in question? Check the version of **msi.dll** in C:\Windows\system32 or equivalent path if Windows is on another drive letter. The last version is at the time of writing 5.0.7601.17807.

Obviously check if the problematic machine is different in other ways: OS version, language version, login user (admin?), disk space, disk errors, etc... The command line to generate a verbose log file is (silent install, with verbose log file):

```
msiexec.exe /I "C:\Test.msi" /QN /L*V "C:\Temp\msilog.log"
```

However, it sounds like you cannot get the engine running at all, and then there will be no log.

Comment: The user is at the latest version of the msi.dll as you just wrote. There cannot be a problem of OS version,disk space or errors as he is able to install other builds successfully. The problem occurs only to some msi builds produced by us. I dont know if we can blame the InstallAware or the user's machine in this case.

Comment: Is it a 32 or 64 bit machine? If you copy the failing MSI back to another computer, does it work there?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem once with my project. The quick solution could be that you try and change the Product code in the project settings and re-build it. And then install this new msi on the same problematic machine. Hopefully your problem would be gone then. If this resolves your problem, do let everybody know about it by marking this answer as useful.